# Que estoy haciendo mal? Tengo este error JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, angularjs, json

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio con PHP y Angular JS, el error completo es este:

[image: Error]

Y lo vota justo cuando estoy haciendo una consulta, utilizo un controller.js y dos php, uno es read_products que sirve de intermediario y el otro es de products, en el cual hago toda la consulta a la base de datos. No se que estoy haciendo mal, ya que lo vi en un tutorial pero no he podido resolver este error.

**controller.js**

```js
$scope.getAll = function(){
            $http.get("read_products.php").success(function(response){
                $scope.names = response.records;
            });
        }
```

**read_products.php**

```html
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 
 
// include database and object files 
include_once 'config/database.php'; 
include_once 'objects/product.php'; 
 
// instantiate database and product object 
$database = new Database(); 
$db = $database->getConnection();
  
// initialize object
$product = new Product($db);
  
// query products
$stmt = $product->readAll();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
  
// check if more than 0 record found
if($num>0){
      
    $data="";
    $x=1;
      
    // retrieve our table contents
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // extract row
        // this will make $row['name'] to
        // just $name only
        extract($row);
          
        $data .= '{';
            $data .= '"id":"'  . $id . '",';
            $data .= '"name":"' . $name . '",';
            $data .= '"description":"' . html_entity_decode($description) . '",';
            $data .= '"price":"' . $price . '"';
        $data .= '}'; 
          
        $data .= $x<$num ? ',' : ''; $x++; } 
} 
 
// json format output 
echo '{"records":[' . $data . ']}'; 
?>
```

**products.php / funcion para la consulta**

```html
function readAll(){
 
    // select all query
    $query = "SELECT 
                id, name, description, price, created 
            FROM 
                " . $this->table_name . "
            ORDER BY 
                id DESC";
 
    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
     
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();
     
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el JSON que estás parseando? Puede que el objeto JSON recibido no sea un objeto JSON correcto.

Comment: Deberías usar `$http.get().then` en lugar de `$http.get().success`

Comment: Hola! Que te aparece en la pestaña 'network' en la consola de chrome o Firefox?

Comment: El objeto JSON lo envío de esta manera 

echo '{"records":[' . $data . ']}';

Probare cambiandolo aunque no sea la diferencia

En la pestaña de network no aparece nada con respecto al erroe

Comment: No funciona cambiando $http.get().then en lugar de $http.get().success sigue tirando el mismo error

Comment: @EmilianoLara El cambio de `success` por `then` no es la solución a tu problema pero debes hacerlo ya que usar `success` es obsoleto.

Answer (score 1):

PHP tiene un método para serializar los JSON. 
El response que estas enviando no lo es (aunque en formato si). 
En el header deberías especificarlo como un JSON (Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8).

Para no estar codeando esto, mejor consulta la documentación de PHP para serializar correctamente.

Fíjate acá: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php/)

Answer (score 0):

El problema son las cabeceras que no deben ir al inicio

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

en curl hay una opccion

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    'cache-control: no-cache',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica primero no estar imprimiendo otros strings en los demás includes que tienes arriba.

También, utiliza la función json_encode() para obtener el resultado en JSON de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/json");

/*Other data*/

$data = Array("id"=>$id,"name"=>$name);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```